# Return value in recursive algorithm without using global variables

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, global-variables

Write an algorithm that returns the `name` of a certain `activity`.

In our function we are given the value of the `activity`, and if it exists in our array return the value of the `name`:

Example:

```
findMatch('scuba diving', activityItems) = 'Beach'

const activityItems = [
    {
        name: 'Sunday',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Gym',
                activity: 'weights',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Monday',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Track',
                activity: 'race',
            },
            {
                name: 'Work',
                activity: 'meeting',
            },
            {
                name: 'Swim',
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'Beach',
                        activity: 'scuba diving',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Pool',
                        activity: 'back stroke',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],    
    },
    {} ...
    {} ...
];
```

My implementation:

```
let match = '';
const findMatch = (activity, activityItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < activityItems.length; i += 1) {
        if (activityItems[i].activity === activity) {
            match = activityItems[i].name;
            return match;
        }

        if (activityItems[i].items && findMatch(activity, activityItems[i].items)) {
            return match;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

However I do not like my implementation because of the use of a global variable. Is there a way I can return the correct value without it?

I tried things like:

```
const findMatch = (activity, activityItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < activityItems.length; i += 1) {
        if (activityItems[i].activity === activity) {
            return activityItems[i].name;              
        }

        if (activityItems[i].items) {
            return findMatch(activity, activityItems[i].items);
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

But this always returns false or undefined.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why keep that global variable in the first place? Just return the name if it exists, or `null` if not. Keep the result of a recursive search in a *local* variable, and only return if it is not `null`:

```
const findMatch = (activity, activityItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < activityItems.length; i++) {
        if (activityItems[i].activity === activity)
            return activityItems[i].name;

        if (activityItems[i].items) {
            let match = findMatch(activity, activityItems[i].items);
            if (match) return match;
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The built in `Array.prototype.find` method returns `undefined` when no value is found, so I'd follow that example by using `undefined` as the no-match result.

I'd also use `for of` in implementing your function.

```js
const activityItems = [
  {name: 'Sunday',items: [{name: 'Gym',activity: 'weights'}]},
  {name: 'Monday',items: [{name: 'Track',activity: 'race'},
      {name: 'Work',activity: 'meeting'},
      {name: 'Swim',items: [{name: 'Beach',activity: 'scuba diving'},
          {name: 'Pool',activity: 'back stroke'}]}]},
  {},
  {}
];

const findMatch = (needle, haystack) => {
  for (let {activity, name, items} of haystack) {
    if (activity == needle) return name;
    if (items && (items = findMatch(needle, items))) return items;
  }
  return undefined;
}


console.log(findMatch('scuba diving', activityItems))
```

This also uses destructuring assingment in the `for of` loop to grab the specific properties you want. I reused the `items` variable to assign the result of the recursive call. You don't need to do this, but it makes it a little shorter without having to declare a variable just for this purpose.

---

Here's a version using `.reduce()` to help satisfy the linter, but now we've lost short circuiting :-(.

```js
const activityItems = [
  {name: 'Sunday',items: [{name: 'Gym',activity: 'weights'}]},
  {name: 'Monday',items: [{name: 'Track',activity: 'race'},
      {name: 'Work',activity: 'meeting'},
      {name: 'Swim',items: [{name: 'Beach',activity: 'scuba diving'},
          {name: 'Pool',activity: 'back stroke'}]}]},
  {},
  {}
];

const findMatch = (needle, haystack) => {
  return haystack.reduce((res, {activity, name, items}) =>
    res !== undefined ? res :
    activity == needle ? name :
    items && findMatch(needle, items)
  , undefined)
}


console.log(findMatch('scuba diving', activityItems))
```

---

One more version, using functional techniques, without built in methods. If functional coding is what you were after, I'd take this approach.

```js
const activityItems = [
  {name: 'Sunday',items: [{name: 'Gym',activity: 'weights'}]},
  {name: 'Monday',items: [{name: 'Track',activity: 'race'},
      {name: 'Work',activity: 'meeting'},
      {name: 'Swim',items: [{name: 'Beach',activity: 'scuba diving'},
          {name: 'Pool',activity: 'back stroke'}]}]},
  {},
  {}
];

const findMatch = (needle, haystack) => {
  if (!haystack || !haystack.length) {
    return undefined;
  }
  const {activity, name, items} = haystack[0];
  return activity == needle ? name :
         findMatch(needle, items) || findMatch(needle, haystack.slice(1));
}

console.log(findMatch('scuba diving', activityItems))
```

---

OK, one more. This is a small variation on the last one. Since we're talking about purely functional programming using tail recursion, it's useful to define parameters that separate the head from the tail. The *spread syntax* and *rest syntax* makes this easy.

```js
const activityItems = [
  {name: 'Sunday',items: [{name: 'Gym',activity: 'weights'}]},
  {name: 'Monday',items: [{name: 'Track',activity: 'race'},
      {name: 'Work',activity: 'meeting'},
      {name: 'Swim',items: [{name: 'Beach',activity: 'scuba diving'},
          {name: 'Pool',activity: 'back stroke'}]}]},
  {},
  {}
];

const findMatch = (needle, head, ...tail) => {
  if (!head) {
    return undefined;
  }
  const {activity, name, items} = head;
  return activity == needle ? name :
         items && findMatch(needle, ...items) || findMatch(needle, ...tail);
}

console.log(findMatch('scuba diving', ...activityItems))
```

Comment: eslint error: `iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations no-restricted-syntax`

Comment: +eslint: change let to cost since activity and name are not reassigned. and then i add another variable instead of reusing items .. then get error above

Comment: So there must be a transpiler involved? What "guide" is not allowing them, and why? The point of using a transpiler is to be able to use useful, new syntax features now, not to avoid them. The `no-restricted-syntax` configuration is expressing an opinion, which is far from absolute. I'll use `for of` over array iteration methods any day of the week. I guess I could rewrite this to use `.reduce()`, but I don't see any gain there.

Comment: I added a `.reduce()` version, but now it is forced to iterate the entire array. You can't get a decent, short-circuiting deep-search with the array iteration methods, unless you do some unpleasant stuff with using a variable outside the callback, which loses most of the point of using a functional approach in the first place.

Comment: Added another version that is purely functional. Doing a search revealed that people who wish to disallow `for-of`, seem to do so out of a desire for functional purity. If that's truly desired, I'd use the last way, though there's nothing wrong with imperative programming. Funny that a `for` loop isn't then considered "restricted syntax"...